# Can I specify the auto-generated property name when using the [ObservableProperty] attribute with CommunityToolkit.MVVM?

Tags: community-toolkit-mvvm

Is it possible to specify the name of the auto-generated property for a private field that is decorated with the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute?  For example, if I have a field, `string address`, that has this attribute, the toolkit will generate a string property, `Address`.  Is there a way to force the toolkit to produce a property name other than `Address` while keeping the field name as `address`?

Answer (score 0):

Sergio Pedri [responded to my question](https://twitter.com/blueshift777/status/1619463409522855939) on Twitter. Short answer: No, not until we get partial properties.